# Creating Rows in DataGridView windows form app

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagridview

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewColumn();
            col.Name = Convert.ToString((char)i);
            col.HeaderText = col.Name;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            row.HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                row.Cells[j].Value = " ";
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Above I have my code which I'm trying to populate each row cell with a blank string value. The thing is I get the columns to show up but the rows are not populating... Here is an image of what the output screen looks like with the above code:

[image]

Any help getting the rows to populate correctly would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This code won't execute without throwing exceptions. Please post the actual code that you are executing.

Comment: I created a form and added a DataGridView to the form and changed dock to 'fill' then in the form1.cs file for the Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) I have the code as posted above... that code posted above is the actual code I am using.

Comment: I also changed 'AllowUserToAddRow' to false and 'AllowUserToDeleteRow' to false as well.

Comment: Adding a `DataGridViewColumn` instance throws an exception because the `.CellType` property is null. You have to add a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, or some other derived instance.

Comment: Thank you! that work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way available to do this please try this

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("five", "six", "seven","eight");
```

Or

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, "one", "two", "three", "four");
```

and if you have already one row then

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells["a"].Value = "Name";
row.Cells["b"].Value = 10.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: The issue I was having was not using 'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' for my DataGridView. I have seen the code you posted on MSDN, and that code wasn't actually showing up without the 'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' so what helped was using 'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' and 'DataGridViewTextBoxCell' for columns and rows respectively.